# Unpickle fields using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need SQLAlchemy to check a database table column for occurrences of python-pickled strings (such as `S'foo'\np0\n.`), unpickle them (which in this example case would yield `foo`) , and write them back. How do I do that (efficiently)? (Can I somehow abuse SQLAlchemy's `PickleType`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a way using `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func.substr`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

table.update().where(
    and_(table.c.column.startswith("S'"),
         table.c.column.endswith("'\np0\n."))
    ).values({table.c.column:
              func.substr(table.c.column,
                          3,
                          func.char_length(table.c.column)-8)
             }).execute()
```